# Android RelativeLayout Ripple effect

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, rippledrawable

In my view, I would like a ripple effect to appear whenever a user touches an ImageView in the layout. I've tried wrapping the ImageView inside a RelativeLayout, but it hasn't worked. Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.sample.me.TapActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tap_view_frame"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_tap_image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_tap_image_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_view" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tap_view"
        android:src="@drawable/ram"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tap_name_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/textview_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tap_number_textView"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tap_number_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textview_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tap_name_textView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tap_view_frame" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/tap_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardview_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardview_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardview_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tap_view_frame">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tap_options_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cardview_tap_height" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here is the "ripple_view" drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffa0a0a0">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffa0a0a0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

I have also tried adding in the android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" tag, but that didn't seem to help. Can anyone explain why the ripple is not showing up? I used the same method to enable the effect in my custom buttons and RecyclerView rows, but it is not working for the RelativeLayout. Ideally, I would like to avoid using a third party library for something as simple as this.